# What is a correct way to run web services on tomcat

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat

I've managed to run web services on tomcat, but it feels like I am doing something wrong or *unorthodox*.

As tomcat cannot run WS out of the box - we need to add some missing libraries.

Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/extras.html) states :

> Web Services support (JSR 109)
>
> Tomcat provides factories for JSR 109 which may be used to resolve web
>   services references. Place the generated catalina-ws.jar as well as
>   jaxrpc.jar and wsdl4j.jar (or another implementation of JSR 109) in
>   the Tomcat lib folder.
>
> Users should be aware that wsdl4j.jar is licensed under CPL 1.0 and
>   not the Apache License version 2.0.

I tried to locate these libraries in the tomcat [maven repository](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/maven-jars.html) with no luck.

Googling every library didn't work either - plus even if I find a jar, how to be sure that the versions of the libraries and the tomcat are compatible?

Finally, after some googling I downloaded  libraries from [jax-ws.java.net](https://jax-ws.java.net/)
(jaxws-ri-2.2.10) and copied everything from zip's lib directory to tomcat's lib.

Now, that actually worked, however tomcat throws some `jar not found` on start up (which are obviously irrelevant to web services - as they are executing fine)

This whole process feels messed up. 
Clearly, I am doing something wrong.

So my question is: What is the normal procedure? What **normal** steps should I have taken, in order to **locate libraries needed** and **enable web services** in **tomcat**.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is enough to include **Metro 2.0**  and **JAX-WS 2.2.6** libraries in **war** file and then no extra libraries are needed for tomcat.

The above libraries are available from the Netbeans "Add library" option (project properties).